# clang-format indentation of chained methods

Tags: c++, formatting, clang-format

I would like to format the code as follows:

```
Scene scene;
scene.add_view(view1)
     .add_view(view2)
     .triangulate_views();
```

But it gets formatted:

```
scene.add_view(view1).add_view(view2).triangulate_views();
```

is there any way to get the first formatting with clang-format?